# adverbial markers

Tags: adverbs

1) "Even in those days he played
golf every wednesday.".., in this
sentence there are two adverbial
markers(in those days and every
wednesday) so which marker is considered as
reference time and situation
time? And why?

Comment: The "narrative reference time" of the sentence in isolation is ***those days***, but *in context* it could be some later time (where just this one sentence reflects his (later) thoughts about something he *used* to do *earlier*). I don't know what "situation time" means in a grammatical context.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having two markers as long as they don't disagree. Is there any need to single out one marker to call the "reference time marker"?

Comment: Same examples but different focus:[non-progressive, habitual actions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288984/non-progressive-habitual-actions)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that *even in those days* is a temporal location adjunct and *every Wednesday* is a frequency adjunct. In the former, *those days* is being used anaphorically, i.e. it refers to some contextually given period in past time, while the latter quantifies the situation by marking it as a multiple situation, in this case *every Wednesday*.

Comment: The interpretation of the non-progressive depends on the kind of situation involved. Normally it is perfective with occurrences i.e. dynamic situations, but imperfective with states, whether ordinary or serial. Here my question is what are ordinary and serial states, could you answer with some relevant examples?

Comment: You raised that secondary topic in another question a short while ago, which I believe is being dealt with there. I answered the question that you asked here.